# Creating a dynamic array of arrays using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of arrays. So, for example, let's look at Pascal's Triangle:

```
1
11
121
1331
14641
...
...
```

This is basically an array of length `N`, that has at each index an array of `i+1`.

How exactly do we set that up?

I've tried a little bit using pointers.

I set up an array of pointers like such:

```
int *arr[N];
```

Then I need a pointer `i` to point to an array of `i+1`, so I did:

```
int *i = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        int numArr[j+1];
        arr[*i] = numArr;
        *i++;
    }
```

Am I going the right direction for this? Because I believe I'm supposed to allocate memory for this as I must use `free()` later. Would I use `malloc()` for each array initialization?

Comment: Yes, you must use `malloc`. If you've never used it before, I suggest you try allocating a single `int`, then once that works perfectly, try allocation an array of `int`, and once *that* works perfectly, take a crack at the problem above. (This is a good approach for any new technique.)

Comment: Why bother using a pointer for `i`? Just use `int i` and be done with it. (but yes, you will need to use `malloc` for `numArr`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code could be made extremely simple, if you know what you're doing:

```
int *arr = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (i + 1));
}
```

Of course, you'll need corresponding calls to `free()` further down the line, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: So `free()` would be called when the triangle is complete, and then I just use it once? Or do a for loop and free the memory of each allocated array?

Comment: You would only call `free()` when you've finished with the arrays. And yes, you would need a `for` loop (see edit).